# How to display selected category term in Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, categories

I want to be able to display the selected category term for a custom post type. So, for example parent category is "Industry". Sub-categories are "Restaurants, Web Design, etc.". The Category selected is "Web Design". I need to display "Web Design" on the front end of my website to look like this "Industry - Web Design".

Answer (score 1):

You'd want to try something like this:

```
<div class="yourelement">
    <p>Industry - <?php the_terms( $post->ID, 'industry');?> </p>
</div>
```

I just guessed that the slug for Industry is just industry, but you'll want to double check that.

The Terms Codex goes more into detail on how it functions and shows more options:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_terms

Comment: That should work for custom post types, but if not take a look at this codex as well get_the_terms (https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_terms)

Comment: That didn't seem to do the trick. This is what I found online but this is just displaying all of the terms. I need just the selected terms. 

<?php 
        $term_id = 25;
        $taxonomy_name = 'project-categories';  
        $termchildren = get_term_children($term_id, $taxonomy_name); 
        
        foreach ($termchildren as $child) {
            $term = get_term_by( 'id', $child, $taxonomy_name ); 
            echo '<li><a href="' . get_term_link( $child, $taxonomy_name ) . '">' . $term->name . '</a></li>'; 
        } 
    ?>